# Is there a tool (preferably CLI) to archive online accounts data?

Tags: email, facebook

I'm imagining something that could download your life data from supported services. For example... download the data for my personal account for all of:

- E-mail (probably plenty of CLI tools I could use this for)
- Facebook
- Pinterest
- Other?

Especially in things like Pinterest, link rot is a reality so being able to backup that kind of stuff locally is really handy for data hoarders like myself.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately the various services have differing, *or in many cases **no***, APIs so finding a one size fits all solution is unlikely. I would suggest investing a little time looking into web scraping tools such as [pythons](http://python.org) [mechanize](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mechanize/0.2.5) and [scrapy](http://scrapy.org/) - between them you can automate downloading/updating the offline copies of information from the various services that **you** use.